# Can a MYSQLI connection be reopened WITHOUT instantiating a new object

Tags: php, mysql, oop, object, mysqli

Just a quick question here:

If I choose the object oriented style to interact with my database, ie...

`$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");`

And I then use `$mysqli->close();` to close the connection at some point...

Can I reopen that connection by simply initiating another query `$mysqli->query();`, or do I have to instantiate a new MYSQLI object?

Comment: @YourCommonSense -- Why are the antique answers here not sufficient?

Comment: @RickJames there is a quite recent one :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you have to instantiate a new MYSQLI object. You can use the same variable `$mysqli` though but you have to write this code again:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Answer (score 6):

Although it is not in the documentation, `mysqli::connect()` is a method, and you can use it to "reconnect" your object -appears to just be an alias for the constructor.

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$name = 'storage';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
// Do stuff...
$mysqli->close();
// Later on...
$mysqli->connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);
```

Comment: I suspect that 1% of the effort is in the "new" and 99% of the effort is in the "connect".

Comment: The documentation of the `connect()` method is in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply not close the mysqli connection and reuse it.

Comment: Not just "could", but "should".

Comment: When you're waiting for data, from an integration, for example, it's a pretty good reason to close the connection and reopen once you received the data. This way you avoid "Too many connections".